# Laravel : Condition on route

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application using **Laravel** in backend.

In `web.php`, I'm defining the following route :

```
Route::get('/customize/{id}', function () {
    if (Profile::where('user_id', User::find(4))) {
        return true;
      }      
      return false;
});
```

Basically I want for example when `user_id` = 4, return `true`. `{id}` is the `id` of the profile. **So if the profile has as user_id of 4, the link will return true, else it's false.**

For some reason whatever the value I'm setting in `user::find()` it returns true.

Example of the profile table :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wr80.png]

Comment: You're never executing the query; you're missing `->first()`, or `->exists()`, etc. Right now, you have a Builder instance, which when checked is always `true`. Change your code to `Profile::where('user_id', 4)->first()` or `Profile::where('user_id', 4)->exists()`; you'll get a `User` instance or `null`, or `true`/`false`, instead of always `true`.

Comment: @TimLewis You are right ! `get` works too apparently. But is my route correct ? For what I want to do ?

Comment: `->get()` returns a Collection, which even if `empty`, will still be `true`, so no, `->get()` does not work :) Also no, because you have 4 hardcoded. It should be `function($id)`, then `Profile::where('user_id', $id)->exists()`. Also, Routes should not return `true` or `false`, but rather a `view()`, `response()` or `redirect()`, or some other valid form of closure.

Comment: @TimLewis I agree with you on the routes. I'm just testing to see if it works first. `$id` seems to work ! Is there any chance I can match `user_id` with the logged user ? I tried `Auth::id()` and it didn't work. Probably because i'm using sessions with React and `localstorage` ?

Comment: Ah ok, if this is just a testing route, ignore the `return` for the time being :) And yes, you _should_ be able to use `auth()->user()->id`, or `auth()->id()` (either one), but only if you're using Laravel's session; ReactJS is a front-end framework and unless you have them connected (somehow; not sure how you'd do that), their sessions are separate from each other.

Comment: @TimLewis For some reason using `auth()->user()->id` give me `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`. I'm using React as a frontend and getting data from Laravel using API. I'm using `localstorage` to get/put data for the login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232104/discussion-between-alyakra-and-tim-lewis).

Comment: Yes, that will happen if `auth()->user()` is `null`, since `null->id` is not valid :) So APIs are "stateless"; `auth()->user()` should always be `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Route::get('/customize/{id}', function () {
    if (Profile::where('user_id', User::find(4))->first()) {
        return true;
      }      
      return false;
});
```

By adding `first()` you will select only one record or null, the result will be true or false.

Answer (score 1):

**Try it first**
**Hope it will helps**

You write a subquery which is `User::find(4)` it will give you an collection object and in your main query you need to check is it exit or not with where condition. So from you need to get id from from your object `User::find(4)->id` then it can match with `user_id`;

```
Route::get('/customize/{id}', function () {

    if (Profile::query()->where('user_id','=', User::query()->find(1)->id)->exists()) {
        return 'true';
    }
    return 'false';
});
```

Comment: Sorry didn't work. Tim's reply have the solution.

Comment: It's ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just like to add, that `Route::fallback()` only handles the `GET` method:

```php
public function fallback($action)
{
    $placeholder = 'fallbackPlaceholder';

    return $this->addRoute(
        'GET', "{{$placeholder}}", $action
    )->where($placeholder, '.*')->fallback();
}
```

If you want to build a fallback for any other HTTP method, than you would have to use an other way:

```php
Route::any('{fallbackPlaceholder}', $action)->where(
  'fallbackPlaceholder', '.*'
)->fallback();
```